# bad characters with asynchrone function in boost asio

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

i have a problem with data transfert in boost::asio.
with the following code :

Server.cpp

```
void        Server::accept(void)
{
    Network::ptr connection = Network::create(this->my_acceptor.get_io_service());
    this->my_acceptor.async_accept(connection->getSocket(), bind(&Server::endCmd, this, connection, placeholders::error));
}

void        Server::endCmd(Network::ptr connection, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (!error)
        {
            connection->Swrite("BIENVENUE");
            this->accept();
        }
}
```

Network.cpp

```
void        Network::Sread(void)
{
    async_read(this->socket, buffer(this->rbuffer), bind(&Network::endRead, shared_from_this(), placeholders::error));
}

void            Network::endRead(const error_code& error)
{
    if (!error)
        {
            this->rcv_msg = this->rbuffer.c_array();
            std::cout << this->rcv_msg << std::endl;
            this->Sread();
        }
}

void            Network::Swrite(std::string msg)
{
    this->msg = msg;
    async_write(this->socket, buffer(this->msg, (int)this->msg.size()), bind(&Network::endWrite, shared_from_this(), placeholders::error));
}

void            Network::endWrite(const error_code &error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        this->Sread();
    }
}

tcp::socket&    Network::getSocket(void)
{
    return (this->socket);
}

Network::ptr                Network::create(io_service &ios)
{
    return (ptr(new Network(ios)));
}
```

When i send a string like "Hello world" to the server with telnet, he write the following content : [image: bug with my serveur]

Who can tell me why the server is writting many unknow characters ?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the string not being nul-terminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `rbuffer.c_array()` isn't a null terminated string but just a array of characters. Printing a character array to `cout` assumes that the array is null terminated, which in this case causes the memory after the end of the array being included in the output.

You should create a `std::string` from the data before trying to print it:

```
std::string received(rbuffer.c_array(), rbuffer.size());
std::cout << received;
```

(Assuming `rbuffer` has a `size()` method or something equivalent)

Comment: thanks ! it's working thanks to you !! :) Now i'll try to build a binary protocol with headers and structures.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your readHandler (Network::endRead()) is missing an argument. There is no way to determine how many bytes were read from the stream. My callback usually looks like this (but I call async_read_some()):

```
void HandleAsioRead(const boost::system::error_code& rErrorCode,
                    std::size_t nBytesTransferred)
```

Then I would null terminate the string I've read from the stream before printing.

Edit:
My call to async_read_some() looks like this:

```
    m_Socket.async_read_some(
        asio::buffer(m_RawBuffer, MaxBufferSize),
        bind(&HandleAsioRead,
             this,
             asio::placeholders::error,
             asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Comment: thanks ! it's good tips. thanks to this, i'll check the size of header in my binary protocol. :)

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with your binary protocol. The "byteTransferred" in the callback indicates how many bytes were taken off the stream. Without that, you can't know how many bytes in the buffer are  valid. You "protocol" should indicate when you have a complete message. If you are using telnet to connect to your server, a message ends probably at the newline character.